# How to solve JavaFX ContextMenu source node?

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have multiple `CheckBox`es in the user interface I created in the FXML file.

```
<CheckBox..>
  <contextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
      <items>
        <MenuItem text="%uncheckall" onAction="#uncheckAll" />
        <MenuItem text="%checkall" onAction="#checkAll" />
      </items>
    </ContextMenu>
  </contextMenu>
</CheckBox>
...
```

All `CheckBox`es use the same methods, i.e. `uncheckAll` and `checkAll`.
How can I return `ContextMenu`'s source `Node` i.e. `CheckBox` in the handling methods from `Event`?

```
@FXML private void uncheckAll(Event event) {
  MenuItem mni = (MenuItem)event.getSource();
  ContextMenu cm = mni.getParentPopup();
  ...???
}
```

Comment: why - what exactly do you want to achieve? smells like mis-use - use a dedicated action for each and you won't have the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be anything in the API for obtaining the owner of a `Node`'s context menu, however the ancestor class of `ContextMenu` has method [setUserData](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Window.html#setUserData(java.lang.Object)). You can set the `CheckBox` as the *user data* of the `ContextMenu`. Here is an example using code only, i.e. not FXML.

```java
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox("check");
MenuItem mi = new MenuItem("menu item");
mi.setOnAction(this::uncheckAll);
ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu(mi);
cm.setUserData(cb);
cb.setContextMenu(cm);
```

Then, in your `uncheckAll` method, you can retrieve the `CheckBox` via method `getUserData`.

```java
@FXML private void uncheckAll(Event event) {
    MenuItem mi = (MenuItem) event.getSource();
    ContextMenu cm = mi.getParentPopup();
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) cm.getUserData();
}
```

### Edit

In FXML simply add a `userData` attribute to the `ContextMenu` tag.

```
<ContextMenu userData="cbxGroup1">
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don’t actually need to work out which checkbox the context menu is attached to.

Your task can probably be accomplished through standard fxml injection into a controller.

Assign the checkbox an fx:id in your fxml:

```
fx:id="cb"
```

Inject it in your controller:

```
@FXML private CheckBox cb;
```

After the fxml is loaded, you can refer to the check box by name `cb` anywhere in the controller, including in an event handler implementation.

```
@FXML private void uncheckAll(Event e) {
    // you can refer to cb directly here.
}
```

As you have multiple checkboxes in your interface, do all of the above multiple times, including the event handler definition.

If you want to share common processing for the event handlers, you can call a separate method, passing in the reference to the checkbox associated with the event handler.

```
@FXML private CheckBox cb1;
@FXML private CheckBox cb2;

@FXML private void uncheckAllForCb1(Event e) {
    uncheckAll(cb1);
}

@FXML private void uncheckAllForCb2(Event e) {
    uncheckAll(cb2);
}

private void uncheckAll(CheckBox sourceBox) {
    // take action for box.
}
```